# C++ - Passing STL map by reference to a templated function

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

What is wrong in this code as I am getting segmentation fault
It seems returning map by value is not problematic.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
T myMapIntersect(T& left, T& right)
{ }

int main()
{
    map<string, int> m;
    m["aa"] = 1;
    m["bb"] = 1;
    m["vf"] = 1;
    m["hh"] = 1;

    myMapIntersect< map<string,int> >(m, m);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: OT: you probably shouldn't include directly stuff from `bits`.

Comment: @AmiTavory Why?

Comment: um, where's the return in `myMapIntersect`?

Comment: Because it's a convention for things that are not guaranteed to remain fixed. Hypothetically, in the next version, the file will be `bits/std_cpp.hpp`. The outer directory files would modify accordingly, and they are the ones you should directly use.

Comment: See [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: It completely separates you from learning something you *should learn* : namely what constructs are provided by what headers from the standard library. Including a half-million lines of headers when all you need is `<map>` and `<string>` isn't instructive at all.

Answer (score 2):

You need to return in your function

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
T myMapIntersect(T& left, T& right)
{
    return left;
}

int main()
{
    map<string, int> m;
    m["aa"] = 1;
    m["bb"] = 1;
    m["vf"] = 1;
    m["hh"] = 1;

    myMapIntersect< map<string,int> >(m, m);
    return 0;
}
```